# How to make a functional query in solr to boost result

Tags: php, solr

I have 3 fields **product_rating** ranging from 1-5 , **merchant_rating** ranging from 1-5 and **deal_price** .

How can I make a functional query so that i can have the products with product_rating and merchant_rating maximum and doc has a deal price?

How can I put a score field to all these fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by a function query using the max value of `product_rating` and `merchant_rating`, while using a filter query to limit the set of documents to those that have a `deal_price`.

```
&sort=max(product_rating,merchant_rating) desc&fq=deal_price:[* TO *]
```

This requires that you're at least on Solr 3.2, as the ability to use two field names in `max()` was added in that version.